# Check two unique values, sql

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, unique-constraint

I have one table, contains two columns **A** and **B** with a unique value constraint.
When the user enter new values **A1** and **B1** into database, i want to check that **A1** doesn't exist in **A** column and **B1** also doesn't exist in **B** column.

--Edit

Those two columns already unique in database. I want to write a query to search for the given values, if the return values is null, then the user can add the new values **A1** and **B1**. if there was a match then i will give the user message that he can't add these values.

Comment: do you mean both values of column does not exists or either of the two?

Comment: @JW웃 the both of the values must be unique.

Comment: Sounds like you are unaware that you can create a unique constraint on a **set** of columns.

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server or another?

Comment: You check. They don't exist. You decide to submit. In the meantime, someone else added them, so the unique constraint rejects the insert. Since you have to write your code to deal with this situation *anyway*, just write that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which of there do you want?

1. A unique independently of other columns
2. B unique independently of other columns
3. A and B pairs unique independently of other columns

Each option requires a unique constraint (or index) on

1. A
2. B
3. Both (A,B)

All SQL dialects allow you to set multiple columns in constraints

Classic SQL would be this. I assume A and B are varchar here

```
INSERT mytable (A, B)
SELECT 'A1', 'B1'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE A= 'A1' AND B = 'B1')
```

This is not safe for concurrency, so there are nicer options

- For SQL Server 2008+ you have the [MERGE statment](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-merge-statement-in-sql-server-2008/)
- For MySQL, you have [INSERT IGNORE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

Also, note, you don't usually test first, report to user, allow write. There is no guarantee that the values could be written between SELECT and later INSERT.

Comment: the both of the columns has a unique constrains, i want to write a query to search the given two values and return the result. if i found a match then the user can't add new data.